# Turn off internal hard drives that aren't in use in XP

Tags: hard-drive

I have two internal caviar black hard drives (SATA) in my XP computer and as I only really use one or the other at a time, the other one is needlessly sucking power, generating heat, and of course noise.

Is it possible to turn off an idle hard drive in XP?

(Also, how would you do this is in C# .net 2.0)

Comment: Idle drives should be suspended automatically.

Comment: I'd still like to know how to do this programmatically in addition to setting the correct configuration in XP manually.